# How to get point x and y geometry from a shapefile?

Tags: python, arcgis-desktop, geometry

I have a shapefile of US Cities and I want to get the X and Y coordinate of EACH city in that shapefile. I've tried this:

```
for city in city_cursor:
    geom = city.Shape
    point = geom.getPart()
    citylist_City_Name.append(city.CITY_NAME)
    citylist_Country.append(city.CNTRY_NAME)
    citylist_Admin.append(city.ADMIN_NAME)
    citylist_Population.append(city.Population)
    citylist_X_Coor.append(geom.point.X)
    citylist_Y_Coor.append(geom.point.Y)
```

but I get the error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/workd.py", line 43, in 
    citylist_X_Coor.append(geom.point.X)
AttributeError: 'PointGeometry' object has no attribute 'point'

I don't really understand the error message? How can I fix it? Thanks!

Comment: I notice that this has also been asked on [**Stack Overflow**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16371109/reading-geometry-of-a-shapefile) with same answer given there by someone else.

Answer (score 3):

You just need `point.X` and `point.Y` not `geom.point.X` and `geom.point.Y`.

Alternatively, if you are using ArcGIS for Desktop 10.1 or later then code like that below using the Data Access module should do the same thing but run faster.

```
shpFile = r"C:\temp\cities.shp"
fields = ['CITY_NAME', 'CNTRY_NAME', 'ADMIN_NAME', 'Population', 'SHAPE@XY']

with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(shpFile, fields) as city_cursor:

   for city in city_cursor:
       citylist_City_Name.append(city[0])
       citylist_Country.append(city[1])
       citylist_Admin.append(city[2])
       citylist_Population.append(city[3])
       citylist_X_Coor.append(city[4][0])
       citylist_Y_Coor.append(city[4][1])
```